# Getting error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Tags: android

**Build Gradle of My Parent project:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cnx.dictionarytool"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**BUILD Gradle of module project::**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
configurations {
    smallicu
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.ibm.icu', name: 'icu4j', version: '58.2'
    // Note: you can just replace "smallicu" by implementation
    // and remove the "compile files" part if you do not
    // care about the size of the apk
    /*smallicu 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:57.1'
    implementation files("$buildDir/icu4j-57.1.small.jar") {
        builtBy 'makesmallicu'
    }*/
}

/*task makesmallicu (type:Exec, dependsOn: configurations.smallicu) {
    inputs.file "mksmallicu.sh"
    inputs.file "${configurations.smallicu.resolve()[0]}"
    outputs.dir "$buildDir"
    outputs.file "$buildDir/icu4j-57.1.small.jar"
    // necessary due to gradle bug: GRADLE-2638
    new File("$buildDir").mkdirs()
    commandLine "./mksmallicu.sh", "${configurations.smallicu.resolve()[0]}", "$buildDir/icu4j-57.1.small.jar"
}*/

def utildir = hasProperty("quickdicUtilDir") ? quickdicUtilDir : "Util"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    lintOptions {
        disable "MissingTranslation"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', utildir + "/src"]
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'de.reimardoeffinger.quickdic'
        targetSdkVersion 29
        resConfigs "de", "es", "fr", "it", "ja", "pt", "pt-rBR", "ru", "zh-rCN"
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```

---

I am able to run Parent project independently and I am also able to run module project independently

But when import library project in parent project as module.... I get below error (There are many errors such)

```
error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
                             ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your parent project uses AndroodX libraries while your module uses Android Support Libraries. Migrate your module project to use AndroidX libraries.